# Create Array of same Size

Tags: julia

I have an array

```
a = zeros(2,3)

2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
```

and I want to create a `Bool` array of same size with all values set to `false`.

Comment: I posted a solution below, but I am actually looking for something else. I thought it must be possible to use `similar()` which would kind of feel like the julian solution to me.

Comment: `similar` is possible but would give you an uninitialized matrix. If you want to initialize it use `falses` or `fill`

Comment: Can you specify whether you are looking for an `Array{Bool}`, or a `BitArray`? They are not the same thing. Your solution below returns a `BitArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `zeros` with `Bool` as the type option:

```
julia> zeros(Bool, size(a))
2×3 Matrix{Bool}:
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be:

```
size(a) |> falses

2×3 BitMatrix:
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
```

Comment: As a quick note to non-Julia readers, `|>` is a fancy operator that rearranges chained function calls syntactically. Thus, this expression is equivalent to `falses(size(a))`.  At this scale, the benefit is debatable, but if you find yourself nesting functions 4 deep or creating lots of temp variables, you might prefer `f(x) |> g |> h |> f2` over `f2(h(g(f(x))))` if only because you don't have to count parentheses.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `similar` and `fill!` to achieve what you want.

```
julia> a = zeros(2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> fill!(similar(a, Bool), false)
2×3 Matrix{Bool}:
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
```